# Excel VBA - If Statement Checking If Value is in Array

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have a lot of variables I have stored in an array. I am trying to use an If Then statement to see if the value of a specific cell is in that array. Here is my code:

```
Dim Vars1 As Variant
Vars1 = Array("Stage 2", "Stage 3", "Stage 4", "Stage 5", "Stage 6", "Stage 7", "WIP Cleanup", 
"Road Test", "Test", "Test Cleanup", "In Bay Inspection", "In Bay Clean Up", "PDI", "PDI 
Cleanup", "Verify", "Complete", "Pictures", "Remove", "ECD", "Platform Install", "#N/A")
'Cuts special delivery parts for Line 3
For RowCounter = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    If InStr(1, Range("F" & RowCounter), "underslung", vbTextCompare) Then 'Underslung
        If Range("B" & RowCounter).Value = "FA Line 3" And Range("N" & RowCounter).Value = Vars1 Then
            Rows(RowCounter).EntireRow.Cut _
                Destination:=Sheets("FA3").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    End If
Next RowCounter
```

I don't think the code is working because it's not cutting and pasting the row. How do I get the if then statement to check and see if the value in "Range("N" & RowCounter)" is in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
...And Range("N" & RowCounter).Value = Vars1 Then
```

This part of your code, you're comparing a single value to an array. You should check if the value is in the array. I don't know off the top of my head if there is an Excel VBA function that does this. It's not difficult to write a function that tests a value is in an array. Here is an idea,

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 0

Function InArray(ByVal pstrVal As String, ByVal pvntArray As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim lngIdx As Long

    For lngIdx = 0 To UBound(pvntArray)
    
        If (pstrVal = VBA.CStr(pvntArray(lngIdx))) Then
            InArray = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    
    Next lngIdx

    InArray = False
End Function
```

To test this function,

```
Sub Testing123()

    Dim Vars1 As Variant

    Vars1 = Array("Stage 2", "Stage 3", "Stage 4", "Stage 5", "Stage 6", "Stage 7", "WIP Cleanup", _
              "Road Test", "Test", "Test Cleanup", "In Bay Inspection", "In Bay Clean Up", "PDI", "PDI", _
              "Cleanup", "Verify", "Complete", "Pictures", "Remove", "ECD", "Platform Install", "#N/A")


    Debug.Print InArray("Testar", Vars1)
    Debug.Print InArray("Test", Vars1)
    Debug.Print InArray("In Bay Inspection", Vars1)
    Debug.Print InArray("Out Bay Inspection", Vars1)
End Sub
```

So where you have your condition, first line in my answer, try this;

```
...And InArray(Range("N" & RowCounter).Value, Vars1) Then
```

Hope this helps

njc

Comment: an element or value is tested for existence in the array, that's what the function does. It is a separate function you can put in the same code sheet as the code you've presented, or in a separate module sheet (not class module). JohnSUN has provided a solution (quite clever too), if you want to test a value in a string.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get around the problem is to stop describing constants as an array. Describe it as

```
Const Vars1 As String = "Stage 2" & vbTab & "Stage 3" & vbTab & "Stage 4" & vbTab _
    & "Stage 5" & vbTab & "Stage 6" & vbTab & "Stage 7" & vbTab _
    & "WIP Cleanup" & vbTab & "Road Test" & vbTab & "Test" & vbTab _
    & "Test Cleanup" & vbTab & "In Bay Inspection" & vbTab & "In Bay Clean Up" & vbTab _
    & "PDI" & vbTab & "PDI Cleanup" & vbTab & "Verify" & vbTab & "Complete" & vbTab _
    & "Pictures" & vbTab & "Remove" & vbTab & "ECD" & vbTab & "Platform Install" & vbTab & "#N/A"
```

and use the same `InStr(...)` as for column F

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what is being proposed. An alternative is to use [**JOIN()**](https://docs.microsoft.com/uk-ua/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/join-function) to get exactly the same string from an already defined array: `Vars1 = Join(Vars1, vbTab)`. In this case, the condition will look like this: `...InStr(1, Vars1,Range("N" & RowCounter).Text, vbTextCompare)...`